# Как получить id выбраного option в datalist

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Хочу получать id option, так как они у меня уникальные. Примеры через value видел - не то, при двух одинаковых value сломается.
Как получить id option?

```
 <input id="inp_navi" type="text" name="navi" list="navi_list"/>      
    <datalist id="navi_list">
        <option
            v-for="(model, index) in l_navi"        
            :value="model.value"
            :id="model.object_id">                    
        </option>                   
    </datalist>
```

P.s. до этого был select в котором была кнопка и параметром передавался id в функцию, которая вызывался при клике, но в datalist добавить кнопку не удалось. Если вдруг знаете как это возможно или чем можно подменить кнопку, для datalist, буду благодарен.

Comment: вы можете сделать что-то наподобие `:id="'option' + index "`

Comment: @ryzen это в input?

Comment: Нельзя на datalist вешать никакие ивенты. Для каких это целей вообще? И в какой момент времени получать? При клике не выйдет такое сделать.

Comment: @MarkMinerov мне требуется получать id выбранного элемента пользователем. Пользователь выбирает и я по id запрашиваю данные для обновления.